# Cant find the default configuration file in the HTC Explorer kernel source

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I downloaded the kernel source for htc explorer (pico-gb-crc-2.6.38-71ff0f2). But I cannot find the default configuration file in /arch/arm/config.

These are the files which are there in the given folder

s3c6400_defconfig
am200epdkit_defconfig
nuc960_defconfig
msm_defconfig
loki_defconfig
sam9_l9260_defconfig
pnx4008_defconfig
simpad_defconfig
pcontrol_g20_defconfig
msm7627a_defconfig
mx27_defconfig
mx1_defconfig
spear600_defconfig
fortunet_defconfig
h7202_defconfig
s3c2410_defconfig
at91sam9263ek_defconfig
magician_defconfig
usb-a9260_defconfig
lart_defconfig
pxa255-idp_defconfig
bcmring_defconfig
cerfcube_defconfig
pxa910_defconfig
ixp4xx_defconfig
pxa168_defconfig
stmp37xx_defconfig
u300_defconfig
eseries_pxa_defconfig
assabet_defconfig
s5p64x0_defconfig
stmp378x_defconfig
ap4evb_defconfig
shannon_defconfig
u8500_defconfig
davinci_all_defconfig
neocore926_defconfig
cns3420vb_defconfig
netwinder_defconfig
cam60_defconfig
h7201_defconfig
stamp9g20_defconfig
em_x270_defconfig
raumfeld_defconfig
netx_defconfig
acs5k_tiny_defconfig
cpu9g20_defconfig
mackerel_defconfig
at91rm9200_defconfig
at91sam9g20ek_defconfig
cm_x2xx_defconfig
usb-a9263_defconfig
spear300_defconfig
collie_defconfig
g3evm_defconfig
dove_defconfig
trizeps4_defconfig
acs5k_defconfig
edb7211_defconfig
colibri_pxa270_defconfig
cm_x300_defconfig
s5pv210_defconfig
colibri_pxa300_defconfig
mv78xx0_defconfig
ebsa110_defconfig
omap1_defconfig
kirkwood_defconfig
pcm027_defconfig
spitz_defconfig
omap2plus_defconfig
at91cap9adk_defconfig
ep93xx_defconfig
realview-smp_defconfig
viper_defconfig
integrator_defconfig
ag5evm_defconfig
mx21_defconfig
spear320_defconfig
imote2_defconfig
at91sam9260ek_defconfig
shark_defconfig
rpc_defconfig
iop33x_defconfig
hackkit_defconfig
nuc950_defconfig
realview_defconfig
ezx_defconfig
xcep_defconfig
at572d940hfek_defconfig
spear310_defconfig
versatile_defconfig
mx51_defconfig
jornada720_defconfig
lpd7a400_defconfig
orion5x_defconfig
pleb_defconfig
h5000_defconfig
lpd270_defconfig
tct_hammer_defconfig
ixp2000_defconfig
iop13xx_defconfig
at91sam9261ek_defconfig
nhk8815_defconfig
s5p6442_defconfig
badge4_defconfig
footbridge_defconfig
mainstone_defconfig
ns9xxx_defconfig
nuc910_defconfig
qil-a9260_defconfig
ixp23xx_defconfig
mini2440_defconfig
lpd7a404_defconfig
neponset_defconfig
pxa3xx_defconfig
lubbock_defconfig
corgi_defconfig
at91sam9rlek_defconfig
h3600_defconfig
mmp2_defconfig
g4evm_defconfig
s5pc100_defconfig
mx3_defconfig
ks8695_defconfig
zeus_defconfig
cpu9260_defconfig
palmz72_defconfig
afeb9260_defconfig
iop32x_defconfig
da8xx_omapl_defconfig

Is there any way to find out the default configuration file?

Comment: Do you have a /proc/config.gz on the device?

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I don't have an android phone to pull the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably an HTC phone will have some CONFIG_HTC items set:

```
pico-gb-crc-2.6.38-71ff0f2$ grep -lR 'CONFIG_HTC.*=y' * 

arch/arm/configs/msm7627a_defconfig
arch/arm/configs/magician_defconfig
```

The first result looks more plausible (it has more hits when the -l flag is ommitted), but let's be sure - an android device will normally have some ANDROID config options, too:

```
pico-gb-crc-2.6.38-71ff0f2$ grep -l ANDROID arch/arm/configs/*
arch/arm/configs/msm7627a_defconfig
```